# ERROR TypeError: "user is null" on logout

Tags: angular

Hi i'm using angular 7 and i use this to view my photo  :

```
this._authService.getAuthStatusListener()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log("user", user.thumbnail.encoded)
        if (user.thumbnail.encoded) {
            this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;" + user.thumbnail.encoding + ", " + user.thumbnail.encoded);
        } else {
            this.photo = "assets/images/avatars/user.jpg"
        }

    });
```

And this is the html :

```
<div *ngIf="user" class="user" fxLayout="column" [ngClass]="fuseConfig.layout.navbar.secondaryBackground">

    <div *ngIf="user" class="h3 username">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</div>
    <div class="h5 company hint-text mt-8">{{ user.company }}</div>
    <div class="avatar-container" [ngClass]="fuseConfig.layout.navbar.primaryBackground">
        <img class="avatar"  src="assets/images/avatars/user.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

and when i sign out my application i have this error in my console

ERROR TypeError: "user is null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a :

```
console.log("user", user.thumbnail.encoded)
```

But when you logout, user is null so you can access user.thumbnail.encoded
Solution :

```
    if (user && user.thumbnail && user.thumbnail.encoded ) {
        console.log("user", user.thumbnail.encoded)
        this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;" + user.thumbnail.encoding + ", " + user.thumbnail.encoded);
    } else {
        this.photo = "assets/images/avatars/user.jpg"
    }
```